# Python - printing out all references to a specific instance

Tags: python, oop, garbage-collection

I am investigating garbage collection issues in a Python app. What would be the best readable option to print out all variables referencing a specific instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the inspect module.  This script helps if you just want to track down reference leaks:

http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph.py http://mg.pov.lt/blog/hunting-python-memleaks http://mg.pov.lt/blog/python-object-graphs.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [Finding objects' names](http://pythonic.pocoo.org/2009/5/30/finding-objects-names), it prints all names that reference a given object.

Comment: At present, this link gives "500 Internal Server Error"